# is it possible to use $("btn").submit for runtime created buttons?

Tags: jquery, json

I did everything I could to alert something after submitting a button which has been created in runtime, I gained no success. The code is simple so I don't post here.
Is there problem with runtime buttons that can't accept  submit event?

```
$(".simple_btn").click(function(e){
     $("this").submit(function(){
          return false; 
     });
});
```

Comment: Would you post the code here please

Comment: I recommend: `$( yourForm ).on( 'submit', function () { ... });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`.submit`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event applies to forms not buttons. So instead of:

```
$('#btnId').submit(...)
```

you probably want:

```
$('#formId').submit(...)
```

And as far as subscribing to events such as submit to dynamically added elements (that would be a `<form>` in your case) you could use the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method if you are using jQuery 1.7 or the [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method if you are using an older version.

```
$(function() {
    // subscribe to the submit event of a form with id="formId"
    // that is either currently present in the DOM or it will be
    // added dynamically in the future
    $(document).on('submit', '#formId', function() { 
        // the form was submitted => do some processing ...
    }); 
});
```

And here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p9NCm/) in which we use the `.on()` method to subscribe to the submit event of a form that is dynamically added to the DOM at a later stage.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body").append('<input  type="submit" id="aaa"/>')

 $(“body”).on('click','#aaa',function ()
{
$('form').submit();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly submit event is usually used on form.

Secondly, for runtime creation, use the delegate Or on method.